# Minimum of $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2}.$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Find the minimum of $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2}.$$

The problem is from an inequality book. While I was doing the problem myself, I got the following results:

From [Minkowski's inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Minkowski_Inequality), we have
$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2}\\ \geq \sqrt{(a+a-1+a+a-1)^2+(b+b-1+b+b-1)^2}\\ =\sqrt{(4a-2)^2+(4b-2)^2}\\ \geq \sqrt{8(2a-1)(2b-1)} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{[From AM-GM]}$

Equality holds when $4a-2=4b-2\implies a=b$. And the minimum $\sqrt{8(2a-1)(2b-1)}=0$ when $a=b=\frac 12$.
Here, everything seemed right to me. But when I plugged in $a=b=\frac 12$ in the original expression, I didn't get the minimum $0$ rather I got $2\sqrt 2$.

When I checked the solution in the book, a geometric solution was given and the minimum was indeed $2\sqrt 2$. So, I couldn't find where my mistake is. It will be helpful for me if someone can find that. Other algebraic solutions are also welcome.
I'm not good at inequalities, so pardon silly mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: That's an inequality at the end,  which says it's bigger than or equal to 0 at your point,  not equal to 0.

Comment: Your bounds isn’t wrong, but the first inequality isn’t tight. Think about when equality holds with Minkowski.

Comment: (Tangential to verifying the solution, looking at the alternate solution) The geometric idea is quite natural. Indeed, note that the question asks for minimizing the sum of distances from (the vertices of a square) $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ to this point, and it is reasonable to expect that the minimum is at the center of this square.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon The book also has the same solution as mentioned.

Comment: @Milten I didn't completely get your point. Isn't Minkowsky a tight one? And doesn't the equality hold when $b_i=ca_i$?

Comment: You seem to say that "I didn't get the minimum 0 rather I got 2 root2" So you got 2 root 2 as answer and this is only the answer. What is the problem?

Comment: @JitendraSingh The minimal is defined such that 0 is the minimum (by the equality condition of AM-GM). But when I got $2\sqrt 2$ in the original expression, it seemed contradictory to the assumption (at least to me).

Comment: But this inequality can never result in 0 unless a and b are complex @Unknown so 0 can't be the answer

Comment: @JitendraSingh See my last inequality. That says we can have 0 as a minimum when either $2a-1$ or $2b-1$ equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you misapply Minkowski's inequality.
More accurately:
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2}\\
&\geq\sqrt{2a^2+2(a-1)^2+2b^2+2(b-1)^2}\\
&=2\sqrt{\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}}.\end{align*}
Then it's just like yours.

Comment: @Unknown I don't think they are saying the results are the same (none of your equations are equal to $2\sqrt{\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}}$, unless I am missing something). I think they mean "then solve the problem as you did from here".

Comment: @user1729, thanks a lot.

Comment: @kabenyuk Can you continue the rest of your solution? I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: @Unknown,
Minkowski's inequality is too weak and it will not allow you to find the minimum.

Use the triangle inequality twice
$$
\sqrt{(x_1-z_1)^2+(x_2-z_2)^2}+\sqrt{(z_1-y_1)^2+(z_2-y_2)^2}\geq\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}.
$$
as Jitendra Singh suggests:

1) $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$, $(y_1,y_2)=(1,1)$, $(z_1,z_2)=(a,b)$;

2) $(x_1,x_2)=(1,0)$, $(y_1,y_2)=(0,1)$, $(z_1,z_2)=(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got the minimum $0$ and you wanna ask what is your mistake.

Then each term reduces to $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

So $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{2}$

Just to help you help here is another helpful solution-

> In the cartesian system of coordinates consider the points:
> $O(0,0)$, the origin;
> $A(x,y);B(x,y-1);C(x-1,y-1);D(x-1,y)$.
> $A,B,C,D$ are the vertices of a square with the side $1$.
> Results: $AC=BD=\sqrt2$.
> Denote $M\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2},y-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=AC\cap BD$ the center of the square.

> $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=OA; \sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}=OB; \sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}=OC; \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=OD$.
> Using the triangle inequality:
> $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}=OA+OC\ge AC=\sqrt2$, with equality for $O\in[AC]$.
> $\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=OB+OD\ge BD=\sqrt2$, with equality for $O\in[BD]$.

> Results:
> $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\ge2\sqrt2$, with equality for
> $O\equiv M\Longleftrightarrow x=y=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am already familiar with the geometric solution. It would be more helpful if someone could provide the algebraic solution. But thanks anyways.